# Connection between nodes in NS2

Tags: network

In NS2, I connected one sink node with two source nodes. For that, seperate two agents are created for sink (For example TCPSink) node and connected with source node (TCP). My question is, are these connections form seperate channels or only one channel?

Comment: A single TCP connection is between exactly two peers (application processes).

Comment: @RonMaupin So, does a single TCP connection represents a channel?